# Traefik proxy to s3 site

Tags: amazon-s3, traefik

I'm trying to use Traefik to proxy to an s3 site, but I always get `Internal Server Error` from Traefik, even if I request `/index.html` directly, and the logs just display a 500 error with no extra details. The bucket website works on the AWS provided domain already, but I need to serve this under a static IP.

This is my `file` provider config:

```
http:
  routers:
    my-bucket:
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: "Host(`my-bucket.com`) || Host(`www.my-bucket.com`)"
      service: my-bucket
      middlewares: # Still errors with or without middleware
        - "my-bucket-add-headers"
  middlewares: # Still errors with or without middleware
    my-bucket-add-headers:
      headers:
        customRequestHeaders: # Still errors with Host: my-bucket
          Host: "my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
  services:
    my-bucket:
      loadBalancer:
        passHostHeader: false # Still errors with or without this
        serversTransport: "my-bucket-insecure" # Still errors with or without this
        servers:
          - url: "https://my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
  serversTransports: # Still errors with or without this
    "my-bucket-insecure":
      insecureSkipVerify: true
```

The Traefik dashboard shows me that the router and service are registered and working perfectly fine, but clearly they are not. I don't believe the request is ever even getting to s3. Any idea what's going on here?